# Showing arrow using border and no content

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to replicate a page from Quora to test and practise my HTML+CSS capabilities before I enter new territories with frameworks. However, I've gotten a bit stuck while trying to make an arrow with the border property on CSS. It's the one in the user's dropdown on the right, connecting the menu with the header (see pic, below letter E in orange-red background). I've found out how it works by using no content (width+height: 0) and solid borders with only left, right and bottom displayed. However, and this is the main problem, it seems to be covered by the body element.

Exploring the problem, I thought z-index would help (at least my reading of MDN's info about it lead me to believe that). However, even with a value of 3 it's still covered. I have no clue of how to solve this, so any help would be appreciated

[image: context of the problem]

Repo on GH: https://github.com/Tom4sBeltr4n/quora-replica

Answer (score 0):

As I looked at your Code the problem seems to be that you have set `overflow-y: scroll` to `.dropdown-container--user-dropdown` because of this the div is getting clipped. On removing this the arrow will be visible.

Also, Instead of using static values for aligning the arrow I would recommend using Percentage for better results

```css
/* For Making the Arrow Visible */
.dropdown-container--user-dropdown {
  overflow-y: visible;
}

/* For Positioning the Arrow in a better way */
.dropdown-container--arrow-up {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(100% + 7px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to have more details on how the percentage would improve the position. Is it responsivity?

Also, the [https://www.quora.com/I-have-learned-HTML-and-CSS-What-are-some-simple-sites-I-can-replicate-for-my-practice](original site) has a scroll in the dropdown, so I'd like to know how to have both said scroll and this border arrow thingy.